# Почему при компиляции программы выходят ошибки StackOverflow и то, что индекс находится за границей массива?

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

Пишу программу, имплементацию этой игры (https://www.lemoda.net/javascript/flood-it/index.html), но у я никак не могу понять, где именно у меня ошибка.

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Индекс находился вне границ массива.
   в color_fill.game_array.get_val(Int32 param) :строка 16777215
   в color_fill.color_fill.fill(game_array& a, Int32& current_color, Int32 i, Int32 j) :строка 80
   в color_fill.color_fill.game(game_array& a, Int32& count_turn) :строка 94
   в color_fill.color_fill.initialize(game_array& a):строка 108
   в color_fill.color_fill.$Main():строка 137
   в Program2.Program.Main()
```

Случай со StackOverflow воссоздать не удалось.
Вот сама программа:

```
program color_fill;

uses crt;

const
  n_size = 14;
  n_turn = 25;

type
  game_array = array [1..n_size, 1..n_size] of 1..6;

var
  option, count_turn: integer;
  a: game_array;

function check_win(var a: game_array): boolean;
var
  i, j, c: integer;
begin
  c := a[1, 1];
  result := true;
  for i := 1 to n_size do
    for j := 1 to n_size do
      if (a[i, j] <> c) then
        result := False;
end;

procedure draw(var a: game_array; var count_turn: integer);
var
  i, j: integer;
begin
  textbackground(0);
  clrscr;
  for i := 1 to n_size do
  begin
    for j := 1 to n_size do
    begin
      case a[i, j] of
        1: begin textcolor(12);write('█'); end;
        2: begin textcolor(14);write('█'); end;
        3: begin textcolor(10);write('█'); end;
        4: begin textcolor(11);write('█'); end;
        5: begin textcolor(9);write('█'); end;
        6: begin textcolor(13);write('█'); end;
      end;
    end;
    writeln();
  end;
  textcolor(15);
  writeln(count_turn, '/', n_turn);
  if (check_win(a) = False) and (count_turn < n_turn) then
  begin
    textcolor(15);
    writeln('Введите число, чтобы заполнить левый верхний угол:');
    writeln('- 1: Красный');
    writeln('- 2: Желтый');
    writeln('- 3: Зеленый');
    writeln('- 4: Бирюзовый');
    writeln('- 5: Синий');
    writeln('- 6: Пурпурный');
  end;
  if (check_win(a) = True) and (count_turn <= n_turn) then
  begin
    textcolor(15);
    writeln('Вы выиграли!');
  end;
  if (check_win(a) = False) and (count_turn = n_turn) then
  begin
    textcolor(15);
    writeln('Вы проиграли!');
  end;
end;

procedure fill(var a: game_array; var current_color: integer; i, j: integer);
begin
  if (a[i + 1, j] = a[i, j]) and (i + 1 < n_size) then
  begin
    fill(a, current_color, i + 1, j);
    a[i + 1, j] := current_color;
  end;
  if (a[i, j + 1] = a[i, j]) and (j + 1 < n_size) then
  begin
    fill(a, current_color, i, j + 1);
    a[i, j + 1] := current_color;
  end;
  if (a[i - 1, j] = a[i, j]) and (i - 1 > 1) then
  begin
    fill(a, current_color, i - 1, j);
    a[i - 1, j] := current_color;
  end;
  if (a[i, j - 1] = a[i, j]) and (j - 1 > 1) then
  begin
    fill(a, current_color, i - 1, j);
    a[i - 1, j] := current_color;
  end;
end;

procedure game(var a: game_array; var count_turn: integer);
var
  current_color : integer;
begin
  while (count_turn < n_turn + 1) and (check_win(a) = false) do
  begin
    readln(current_color);
    fill(a, current_color, 1, 1);
    inc(count_turn);
    draw(a, count_turn);
  end;
end;

procedure initialize(var a: game_array);
var
  i, j: integer;
begin
  for i := 1 to n_size do
    for j := 1 to n_size do 
      a[i, j] := random(6)+1;
  draw(a, count_turn);
  game(a, count_turn);
end;

begin
  clrscr;
  textcolor(15);
  writeln('ЗАПОЛНИ КВАДРАТ');
  writeln('---');
  writeln('Выберите опцию:');
  writeln('- 1: Начать игру');
  writeln('- 2: Прочитать правила');
  writeln('- 3: Выйти из игры');
  writeln('---');
  repeat
    readln(option);
  until (option = 1) or (option = 2) or (option = 3);
  if option = 2 then
  begin
    writeln('---');
    writeln('Заполните весь квадрат, начиная с');
    writeln('верхнего левого угла, не больше чем');
    writeln('за 25 ходов!');
    writeln('---');
    writeln('Выберите опцию:');
    writeln('- 1: Начать игру');
    writeln('- 2: Выйти из игры');
    writeln('---');
    readln(option);
  end;
  if option = 1 then initialize(a);
end.
```

Comment: Я нашел ошибку в том, что проверки на существования индекса почему после сравнения

Comment: Это я нашел эту ошибку.

Comment: Я увидел комментарий уже потом, и еще там суть не была сама высказана, но все равно спасибо (Спасибо за поправки)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из `game` Вы вызываете `fill` с индексами `1, 1`:

```
fill(a, current_color, 1, 1);
```

Что будет во время этой проверки

```
if (a[i - 1, j] = a[i, j]) and (i - 1 > 1) then
```

если индексация Вашего массива начинается с единицы?

Поменяйте:

```
if (i - 1 >= 1) and (a[i - 1, j] = a[i, j]) then
```

везде, где это делается.